# Is it possible to use string literal types in AssemblyScript?

Tags: assemblyscript

Is it possible to create a string literal type in AssemblyScript that resembles the `type` keyword used in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)?

TypeScript example:

```ts
export type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently:

```
> asc assembly/index.ts --target debug

ERROR AS100: Not implemented: union types
   :
 1 │ export type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar';
   │                              ~~~~~
   └─ in assembly/index.ts(1,30)
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/2300) open.